# how to solve using dart .Given a year, return the century it is in

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-polymer

Given a year, return the century it is in. The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.

```
Example

For year = 1905, the output should be
solution(year) = 20;
For year = 1700, the output should be
solution(year) = 17.
Input/Output

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (dart)

[input] integer year

A positive integer, designating the year.

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ year ≤ 2005.

[output] integer

The number of the century the year is in.
```

Comment: Not nice to use Stack Overflow to answer your homework question or employer candidate test. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
int getCentury(int year) => (year - 1) ~/ 100 + 1;
```

Comment: thanks, Rahul brother you know where did I get the question form? code signal

Comment: Don't forget to vot.e for my question. brother

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
void main() {
   
  int year1 = 1905;
  int year2 = 1700;
  print('year1 : ${getCentury(year1)}');   //20
  print('year2 : ${getCentury(year2)}');   //17
}

int getCentury(int year){
  if(1 > year || 2005 < year){
    return 0;
  }
  
  int century = year ~/ 100;
  int temp = year % 100;
  
  if(temp != 0){
    century += 1;
  }
  
  return century;
}
```